# catkin migration from rosbuild package does not mention Makefile

Tags: ros, catkin, makefile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the Makefile in the package is needed any more, but neither of these pages mention it:

- [migrating from rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild)
- [convert rosbuild to catkin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/convert_rosbuild_to_catkin)

If I am correct that it is no longer needed, I'll add it to the documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57939/catkin-migration-from-rosbuild-package-does-not-mention-makefile/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-03-12**:
One reference point: I do not track a Makefile in my groovy branches and they work.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-12**:
Thanks. Seems to work for me, too, but I wanted an "official" answer before updating the docs.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-03-12**:
@joq: Gotcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you no longer should have a Makefile.  CMake will generate one for you in your build directory.

I've updated [migrating from rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) to include that in the steps.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-12**:
Thanks, Tully, that helps.